# Python "finally" clause doesn't execute if "try" clause throws SyntaxError

Tags: python, exception, finally, try-finally

Consider the following code:

```
try:
    a = []
    a[4] = 4
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('h')
finally:
    print('y')
```

The output shows that the finally clause was executed:

```
y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work/finally.py", line 3, in <module>
    a[4] = 4
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

However, if I change the try clause to something like this:

```
[] += [] - []
```

Then the finally clause doesn't get executed:

```
  File "work/finally.py", line 2
    [] += [] - []
    ^
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

What is the reason of this behavior? Where could I read about that? I didn't find it in the docs.

Comment: The reason is that the `try`-clause isn't even entered (which is the condition for the `finally`-block being executed): `SyntaxError`s get raised when trying to parse the file.

Comment: As @ L3viathan said the code is never executed because the SyntaxError occurs while parsing the file. `[] +`= is now allowed, if you want to do a similar thing you could say `lst = [];` and then the `[] +=`. Also be careful because the other part of your statement is not allowed neither