# Selenium node does not kill processes after webrdiver sessions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, celery, selenium-grid

I run `Flask + Celery + Selenium Hub + Selenium Node.

I run a lot of tasks that use Remote webdriver:

```py
class Task:
    def setup_driver(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='url',
            options=chrome_options
        )
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    def teardown_driver(self):
        self.driver.quit()
    
    def run(self):
        self.setup_driver()
        try:
            pass
            # do some logic
        finally:
            self.teardown_driver()
```

Always I call `driver.quit()` on the end of task
My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
      - ./conf.yaml:/conf.yaml
      - ./db:/db
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: 'uwsgi app.ini'

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
    - 6379:6379

  celery:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./db:/db
    command: celery -A app.celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO

  celerybeat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A app.celery_app beat --loglevel=INFO --scheduler common.scheduler.TaskLockScheduler

  chrome-node-1:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:91.0
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=300
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"

  chrome-node-2:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:91.0
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=300
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6901:5900"

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

After few hours htop show me that information:
[image]
[image]
A lot of node and hub processes.

So my question: why hub and node does not kill this processes? A use `driver.quit()` after each session.

Answer (score 0):

I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262379/does-finally-always-execute-in-python) that `finally` block may not be executed in [several cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706269/python-finally-clause-doesnt-execute-if-try-clause-throws-syntaxerror).
So, to say more specifically we need to see the entire code inside your `try` block, but generally it is possible that `finally` block will be skipped.
If so, this may describe skipping the `teardown_driver()`  method where `self.driver.quit()` is involved.